# How to get error if angular crashes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I capturing errors in angular just by global handler and sending this to other service through rest api to store and make statistics. All works well but how to capture an error when angular crashes? Of course if angular crashes handler and sending service will wont work.
Some script in index.html which will check if there is any angular syntax? How to do it in right way?

Comment: Add a listener on [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Comment: when you deploy your application , there will be no angular to crush. there will just .js and .css and .html files. At that time only if you'r server crush , you'r application will crush too.

Comment: Apps don't crush, they crash (unless are written by Jon Skeet, then they don't crash either)!